# C programming with arrays

Tags: c, arrays

[This was the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFk4Z.jpg)

```
int num,square;

int array1[100];
int array2[100];

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    printf("please enter the number %d:",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num==-1){
        break;
    }
    else
        array1[i]=num;
}

for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
    square=array1[j]*array1[j];
    array2[j]=square;
}

for(int m=0;m<100;m++){
    printf("number %d is %d\n",m,array2[m]);
}
```

this was the program i made but then the user might input only few int so i want to run the loop which prints the second array only the amount of tym the user inputted how can i do that?

Comment: Don't just add a link and say "this is the question". Please add the question itself to your post.

Comment: Write the question in the post. A link is a complement, not a replacement.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and google 'stackexchange homework'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code.

```
int num,square;

int array1[100];
int array2[100];
int i=0;

for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    printf("please enter the number %d:",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num==-1){
        break;
    }
    else
        array1[i]=num;
}
/* This will only calculate square upto the numbers you have entered
   I have changed the condition to <i
 */
for(int j=0;j < i;j++){
    square=array1[j]*array1[j];
    array2[j]=square;
}
/* This will only print upto the numbers you have entered
   I have changed the condition to <i
 */
for(int m=0;m<i;m++){
    printf("number %d is %d\n",m,array2[m]);
}
```

Comment: It is good practice to leave a little explanation instead of just a code dump - anyway +1.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the first loop variable (i) outside the for.

This will remember the point at which the first loop exited.

Then use that for ending second loop instead of a hard-coded value i.e. 100.

```
    int num,square;
    int array1[100];
    int array2[100];
    int i=0;

    for( i=0; i < 100; i++ )
    {
        printf("please enter the number %d:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&num);
        if(num==-1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
            array1[i]=num;
    }

    for( int j=0; j < i; j++ )
    {
        square = array1[j] * array1[j];
        array2[j] = square;
    }
    for(int m=0; m < i; m++)
    {
        printf("number %d is %d\n", m, array2[m]);
    }
```

Comment: you should not encourage use of global veriables.

Comment: @roottraveller That was badly used, I admit. But I meant outside the for loop scope only.

Comment: @roottraveller that is a local variable and not a global. He misswrote that I guess.

Comment: @roottraveller Ok, my bad I used the dreaded word. Means none of the voters cast a comment either. Great.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is when the user enters -1 and breaks the input loop. That will leave parts of `array1` uninitialized. You are not allowed to access the uninitialized variables. Therefore you need to change the next two for-loops like:

```
for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
    //        ^ notice: i instead of 100
    square=array1[j]*array1[j];
    array2[j]=square;
}

for(int m=0;m<i;m++){
    //        ^ notice: i instead of 100
    printf("number %d is %d\n",m,array2[m]);
}
```

This requires that the first loop is written like:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
```

so that `i` is still valid when reaching the next loops.

In this way you avoid accessing uninitialized parts of `array1` and you only print the same amount of values as the user did input (before -1).

Beside that... doing:

```
scanf("%d",&num);
```

is bad. You shall always check the value returned be `scanf` to make sure that it scanned the expected number of values, i.e.

```
if (scanf("%d",&num) != 1)
{
    // Illegal input
    ....
    Add error handling here
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the number of entered numbers in a variable.

To store a product of two objects of the type `int` it is better to use type `long long int`.

Also it is not a good idea to use magic numbers as 100 throughout the code.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 100

int main( void )
{
    int array1[N];
    long long int array2[N];

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( ; n < N; n++ )
    {
        int num;

        printf("please enter the number %zu: ", n + 1);

        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num == -1) break;

        array1[n] = num;
    }


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        long long int square = (long long int )array1[i] * array1[i];
        array2[i] = square;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "number %zu is %lld\n", i, array2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much this adds to OPs real question that wasn't answered by the existing answers - anyway +1